# How to p/invoke this methode?

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, hsm

```
typedef CK_CALLBACK_FUNCTION(CK_RV, CK_CREATEMUTEX)(
CK_VOID_PTR_PTR ppMutex
);
```

regards,

/* I need also to get my hsm informaton via a C# application by P/Invoke PKCS#11*/

Answer (score 2):

Please see this PInvoke.net page:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createmutex

The C# signature is:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateMutex(IntPtr lpMutexAttributes, bool bInitialOwner, string lpName);
```

Comment: Tank's,, but i use cryptoki.dll?

Comment: No, you use kernel32.dll, just like it says.

Comment: ok, thanks, what is the "String lpName" , Have you an idea about pkcs#11 and cryptoki ?

Comment: pinvoke website is a great wiki reference for all these calls.